# Why does MAX work on a column in the middle of an index

Tags: mysql

From what I understand about multi-column indexes, they are only useful if you're using columns starting from the left and not skipping any. As in, when you have an index for `(a, b, c)`, you can query on `a`, `a, b`, or `a, b, c`.

But today I found out that when there's an index (`BTREE` on an InnoDB table) on:

```
some_varchar, some_bigint, other_varchar
```

I can query:

```
SELECT MAX(some_bigint) FROM the_table
```

and the plan for it says:

```
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: the_table
         type: index
possible_keys: NULL
          key: index_some_varchar_some_bigint_other_varchar
      key_len: 175
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using index
```

This seems to disagree with [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html). It's also confusing since the `key` is set, but `possible_keys` isn't.

How does this work in practice? If the key is ordered by `some_varchar` first, (or a prefix of it) how can MySQL get a `MAX` of the second column from it?

(a guess would be that MySQL collects some extra information about all columns in an index, but if that's true - is it possible to see it directly?)

Comment: Thinking about it logically, an index whose first column didn't provide for any filtering, might still be an improvement over a full table scan.  Good question though, the docs make no note of such a thing.

Comment: We could look for other clues.  Is it just MAX/MIN does this?  How about a WHERE, like `WHERE some_bigint > 0`?

Answer (score 2):

My understanding about the indexes was correct, but the understanding of what `Using index` means was wrong.

`Using index` doesn't necessarily mean that the value was accessed via a fast lookup. It simply means that the row data was not accessed. When the `type` is `index` and the `Extra` is `Using index`, it still means that the whole index is being scanned:

From [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html):

> The index join type is the same as ALL, except that the index tree is scanned.

For a `MAX` lookup which is actually using a prefix of an index, the explain looks like this:

```
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: NULL
         type: NULL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: NULL
        Extra: Select tables optimized away
```

Comment: Correct. "Using index" just means that the table data was not accessed. When `type: index` it's an index-scan, which means it will visit all entries in the index, which is potentially expensive. Nevertheless, it still used *only* the index, not the data.